# "Collapse" or "crumble"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> I won't ever forget that moment. The moment I wish never was. I just stepped out of my work that got a call from my mother and came to know the most horrible news that my grandma who raised me and I loved her more than my mother passed on. I remember when I heard that, suddenly time stopped and my ears began to buzz.
>   It was just like......................

a) as if the whole world **[collapsed](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/collapse) over my head**. 
b) as if the whole world **[crumbled](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/crumble) over my head**.

I wonder which choice works here? To me they both work, but I doubt if natives consider "over my head" as redundant.

Comment: I think *crumbled under my feet* would be better for the crumbled option, but *It was as if my whole world had collapsed/crumbled* without the 'over my head' sounds fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More common usage would be:

"the whole world collapsed around me."
or
"the whole world crumbled around me."

but since this is clearly fiction, you are allowed a degree or two of "poetic licence" and there are loads of similar similes available, with slight adjustment, such as "a hole opened up beneath my feet"

Comment: Thank you @Mile Brockington. Do you mean "over my head" as a simile is understandable / common?

Comment: I'm saying that it is understandable, but NOT common.  Incidentally  "It was just like as if ..." as initially suggested by you, isn't too great.

Comment: I wonder what would sound better @Michael Brockington.

Comment: The comment by smock has a much better-sounding / normal example: "It was as if ..."  or  "It was just like ..." is fine too, but don't mix the two.

Comment: Thank you very much @Micke Brockington. So, does it mean that "It was as if ..." or "It was just like" mean the same in this context?

Comment: Yes, both are fundamentally the same phrase.